# Qt4 and Qt5 QPlainTextEdit incompatibility

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, qplaintextedit

I'm trying to build a program via Qt4, which was written on Qt5. My UI form have `QPlainTextEdit` and I receive following errors:

```
'class QPlainTextEdit' has no member named 'setSizeAdjustPolicy'; did you mean 'setSizePolicy'?
     pteNewAddr->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 setSizePolicy

'AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow' is not a member of 'QAbstractScrollArea'
     pteNewAddr->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow);
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I understand it is due to `setSizeAdjustPolicy` was not introduced in Qt4, but Qt4 is my target now, not Qt5.
Still, in QtCreator designer for a `QPlainTextEdit` I have a field `SizeAdjustPolicy` and `ui_*.h` keep regenerating with:

```
<property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
  <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow</enum>
</property>
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Why are you (still) targetting Qt4?

Comment: @m7913d, well I have to take it for granted as the project uses it, it was not me who decided to use QT4

Comment: When you want Qt4 compatibility you must edit your ui files with designer from Qt4.

Comment: It is a kind of mystery for me - "the Qt4 designer" - as the project is already set for Qt4. I guess it can be somehow resolved by deleting `ui` files for this window (keeping `cpp` and `h`) and re-creating them.